# Can't store Data URI to database without stripping + characters

Tags: mysql, database, django, uri

I am trying to grab a reference to images with src's in URI scheme. An example would be the images on google.com/news.

if I alert(escape(saveObj.image)); I get something like below:

```
data%3Aimage/jpeg%3Bbase64%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
```

I pass that from the js file and am using django to get that into a mysql table of type utf8_unicode_ci using modelform.save, but when i examine what's in the database, I see:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0aHBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL/2wBDAQkJCQwLDBgNDRgyIRwhMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjL/wAARCABQAFADASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHAAAAQUBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAABgIDBAUHAQAI/8QAPhAAAgECBAMFBgIGCwEAAAAAAQIDBBEABRIhEzFhBkFRcYEUIjKRobFCwRUjJFKC0QcWJSZiY3Jzg7Lw4f/EABoBAAIDAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMEAAIFBgH/xAAmEQABBAEEAQMFAAAAAAAAAAABAAIDESEEEjFBBRMisVFhcZGh/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwAr7L5pD2gyY5JXEtLGAFY/EU2sR1U2 nXF/pZFKuffViGPW5ximQUEz1cNdPNKms6g8TlWBufDcHyxsdLUmqoYqhiWZ1BYtsSe
```

The key difference is that in my database all of the '**+**' characters from the original have been stripped and replaced with spaces. Any ideas? I'm going blind trying to figure this out! :P

The only javascript I am executing on the src before passing along to webservice via xmlhttprequest (POST, webservice, TRUE) is:

```
escape(image) where image = src of a google news image.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Django URLFields are automatically passed on to the `urlsplit` method and that removes stuff like this since a `+` also means space in urls.

As you can see [here](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/fields.py?rev=12867#L544), the validation of the URLField automatically does this. So you can either use a `CharField` instead or create a custom `URLField` like this:

```
class CustomURLField(forms.URLField):
    def to_python(self, value):
        return value
```

Do note that it won't automatically add http anymore if you do that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I am actually using:
img_link = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

because i am not sure how large the base64 img links get (they seem huge). using models.TextField, is there a similar constraint? I can't seem to find a reason why that would be the case.

Comment: @citizencane: what does your form look like? I'm guessing that some escaping is incorrect somewhere. Also, do note that `escape()` is not the same as `encodeURI()`.

Comment: for that field the form is

class Copies(models.Model):
 img_link = models.CharField(null = True, blank=True, max_length = 3500)

Comment: @citizencane: I've tried it locally and I can't reproduce it at all so I'm guessing that your javascript is escaping this incorrectly. Can you add the relevant javascript/html parts to your question?

Comment: strange the only JS i am executing is escape(image), (also in the edit above) where image is the src of a google news image URI. Alerting this shows the + characters. I send this to the webservice via xmlhttprequest('post',webserviceurl,true)

Comment: That's your problem right there I'm guessing, try `encodeURI()` instead of `escape()`

Comment: thanks! You led me down the right path. it was encodeURIComponent(image) in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Since `+` in a URL means space, the spaces are fine, just so long as you encode the URL again before you query the server for it. It looks like it's also removing the trailing slash.